# i want convert rows to Colums with specific data in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, pivot-table

I have a Array in multiple Time-In  or Time-Out , Break In or Break out.
i want to calculate total duration from **Time-In to Time-Out**

Here is data.

```
const data = 
  [ { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '02:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : 'dgdfgdfg'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '03:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '04:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '05:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '06:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '07:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '232323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  ]
```

here is Input form
[image: you can check input fields for better understanding]

so first Time-in was 2:28 or Time-out 3:28  and hour will  be **1**.
after break-in or break out again  **Time-in is 6:28 or Time-out 7:28**  and hour will  be **1**.
**now hours is 2.**
Please any body suggest how I can get **total duration 2** in using JavaScript , Typescript.

**my suggestion is if i convert above data to get row to Colum with Time-In or Timeout data or calculate duration in next Colum**
**e.g**

```
[ { timeSheetDailyActivityId : 1
  , Time In                  : '02:28'
  , Time Out                 : '03:28'
  , Duraion                  : 1
  , Break In                 : '02:28'
  , Break Out                : '03:28'
  } 
, { timeSheetDailyActivityId : 2
  , Time In                  : '06:28'
  , Time Out                 : '08:28'
  , Duraion                  : 1
  , Break In                 : '02:28'
  , Break Out                : '03:28'
  } 
]
```

[image: to like this]

then i can achieve my goal.

Comment: in fact, you just want to calculate the number of hours started during a time interval?

Comment: what part of the process are you stuck on? granted it's a little intricate, but the basic idea is simple, tally up your array of objects by converting the timestamps into usable numbers and keeping track of the IN vs the OUT. I mocked up something that uses reduce a couple times

Comment: @MisterJojo yes i want number all time-in or time out

Comment: I think it's clear you want that. Re-read the comment by @charlietfl - that's how you get help here